# Video tag full-width IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to achieve a fullwidth display in my site. All is ok in chrome but now the problem is with IE11. It seems that the video itself is not being set to full width.

[image]

As you can see in the image there are black portion in both left and right portion. But if you look at the image below
[image]

As you can see the video here is set to fullwidth. Any idea what's the problem? Below is the css

```
.html--homepage_content {
    video {
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;

        @media #{$mqMediumAndUp} {
            width: initial;
            max-height: initial;
        }
    }

    .video-player-container {
        height: 100vh;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}

.video-player-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;

    video {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;

        @media #{$mqMediumAndUp} {
            width: initial !important;
            height: initial !important;
        }

        object-fit: cover;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="video-player-container content-block__content">
    <video autoplay="" muted="" loop="" playsinline="">
        <source src="http://website.com/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video> 
</div>
```

Comment: you should width:100% for div.. because IE not allow with out width value

Comment: @Ranjithv width is already set to 100%

Comment: just try for all div @MadzQuestioning

Comment: i think object-fit: cover; property is not wotk on IE browser

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`object-fit: cover` is [not supported in IE 11](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit#Browser_compatibility). You could use polyfills for that. Please check [this polyfill](https://github.com/constancecchen/object-fit-polyfill).

You could use it like below, remember to change the `src` of the `polyfill` to yours, it can work well in IE 11:

```
<style>
    .container {
        width: 100%; /* Or whatever you want it to be */
        height: 25em; /* Or whatever you want it to be */
    }

    .media {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover; /* Or whatever object-fit you want */
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <video autoplay="" muted="" loop="" playsinline="" data-object-fit="cover" class="media">
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
<script src="js/objectFitPolyfill.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The video scaling mode probably. Check https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-fit-video-into-entire-div-that-works-on-ie-too/283224 for example.

If it does not work for you and you know the video dimensions, you can always scale it manually wrapping in other div with offset not visible, but it is an ugly sollution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .video-player-container {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .video-player-container video {
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="video-player-container content-block__content">
    <video width="100%" height="240" autoplay="" muted="" loop="" playsinline="" controls>
        <source src="http://website.com/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Video full-width IE check me  -  @MadzQuestioning